# Sequelize - Where clause using the included model attribute

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Using `sequelize`, I need to find all articles that satisfies the following condition: `article.isSecret = false` OR `article.board.managerId = user.userId` OR `article.authorId = user.userId`. Following is the code I wrote:

```js
const articles = await Articles.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Boards, 
        as: 'board', 
        attributes: ['managerId'], 
        required: true, 
    }], 
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [{
            isSecret: false, 
        }, {
            'board.managerId': user.userId, 
        }, {
            authorId: user.userId, 
        }], 
    }, 
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'authorId', 'createdAt'], 
});
```

But the code throwed an error `Unknown column 'article.board.managerId' in 'on clause'`. What is the proper way to load the value of parent model in the where clause? I've tried `$board.managerId$` and `$Boards.managerId$`, but both of them failed to load the value of `article.board.managerId`.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the problem, I would write my solution here to help anyone who faces the same problem. Put the where clause into the included model, in this case, the `Boards` model.

```js
const articles = await Articles.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Boards, 
        as: 'board', 
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [{
                '$article.isSecret$': false, 
            }, {
                managerId: user.userId, 
            }, {
                '$article.authorId$': user.userId, 
            }], 
        }, 
        attributes: ['managerId'], 
        required: true, 
    }], 
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'authorId', 'createdAt'], 
});
```